# How to configure XAMPP based Web Server on an Windows 2012 R2 RDP Server to be accessed worldwide?

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, nat, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to configure XAMPP based Web Server on Windows 2012 R2 RDP Server but after successfully configuring it..I can't access it remotely from the web???

http://163.172.60.186:23456/media_server/

I have changed the port from 80 to 23456 in order to confirm if the ports are being blocked but still no use...so How to make it accessible on web then???

Normally I would do it locally on my PC is to forward the port through NAT and then it would be accessible but I don't see any NAT and neither can I access the Default Gateway to access some sort of Modem/Router in order to configure the NAT???

So anything???

Comment: If your server can't access the internet it's not going to work the other way around. Configure the network properly so you're able to access it in your LAN and afterwards you would indeed setup a port forward.

Comment: @Seth : Internet is working properly on the server...I can access the XAMPP server locally in the server..!

Comment: In that case what do you mean by you don't see any NAT? Just setup the port forward on your router for that machine?

Comment: @Seth : Normally as you can access the router settings from the gateway IP Address but I can't access it so then how to do it???

Comment: You use your machine? It is within your network, right?

Comment: Nope...It's a remote server...in france while I am in Pakistan..! :D :P

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In that case it's probably already connected. You probably just need to adjust your firewall settings to actually allow the server to communicate on that port. My assumption now is that you rented a windows server from some hosting company. If that is not the case you probably need to talk to your network administrators on site to make it accessible.